# Angular: How to solve - Blocked attempt to create a WebMediaPlayer as there are too many WebMediaPlayers already in existence

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular, google-chrome

**Angular: How to solve - Blocked attempt to create a WebMediaPlayer as there are too many WebMediaPlayers already in existence.**

There are number of audio and video object in website, handing its features using play(), pause() methods.

Due to chrome updates (92), now there are limitations on number audio & video tags in single browser tab.

**Please suggest me common javascript code to resolve this issue.**

I tried with:

$('audio,video').remove();

---

$('audio,video').attr('src', '');

though its not getting resolved.. please suggest me javascript or any code.

Comment: did you found any solution for this?

Comment: actually issue was due to chrome updates.. but in next update.. its resolved automatically